# Time invariance of a System

Tags: continuous-signals, control-systems

I have this small question about the time invariance of a system. Which is:

> If the current output is multiplied by the current input (see both are variables) will the system be time variant or time invariant?

To be precise, the question I am dealing with is:
$$ y(n-3) + y(n-1) + y(n)x(n) = x(n-3) $$

I would be glad if anyone could help.

Comment: probably you have a **constraint** that $x[n] \neq 0$. Also do you have anything to say about the **initial conditions** of the solution $y[n]$?

Comment: @Fat32 this is all I have got. It was one of the question in the quiz I had yesterday. I am not able to figure out how to go ahead with this equation.

Comment: Can we assume causality?

Comment: Why did you tag the question with `continuous-signals`, as the equation sounds discrete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this system is time-invariant assuming $x[n]\neq0 $ for all $n $.

The test for this is
$$x_{1}[n]=x[n-n_{0}] $$
$$y_{1}[n]=y[n-n_{0}] $$

So let's first express in terms of just $y[n]$.
$$ y[n]=\frac{x[n-3]-y[n-3]-y[n-1]}{x[n]} $$
Next, we go through the test.
$$y[n-n_{0}]=\frac{x[n-3-n_{0}]-y[n-3-n_{0}]-y[n-1-n_{0}]}{x[n-n_{0}]} $$
Substituting $y_{1}[n] $
$$y_{1}[n]=\frac{x[n-3-n_{0}]-y[n-3-n_{0}]-y[n-1-n_{0}]}{x[n-n_{0}]} $$
$$y_{1}[n]=\frac{x[n-3-n_{0}]-y_{1}[n-3]-y_{1}[n-1]}{x[n-n_{0}]} $$
And finally substituting $x_{1}[n] $
$$y_{1}[n]=\frac{x_{1}[n-3]-y_{1}[n-3]-y_{1}[n-1]}{x_{1}[n]} $$
Because the shifted sequence has the exact same relationship, it is said to be time-invariant. Most systems that don't alter $n$ or $t$ meet this. Be wary of anything multiplying or otherwise messing with the vector arguments beyond simple delays.

Comment: I think I get it. The point which perplexed me was the x(n)y(n). And we know that when the coefficients are time varying then the system is time varying.

Comment: Not necessarily. The coefficients on the _indices_ being time-varying would be a red flag, but the normal impulse coefficients can be time varying and keep the overall system time-invariant. Time-invariant just means that the relationship between input and output is independent with regards to shifting (the same input shifted left or right $n_{0}$ will give the same output shifted the same manner). If I answered your question, please mark the thread as solved.